# What is the difference between __int<size> and "char, short, int, long long int"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, definition

I am surprised to see also my C++ compiler supports `__int8`, `__int16`, `__int32`, and `__int64`; But I just see they are equivalent to `char`, `short`, `int`, and `long long`. What is the difference between them?

```
sizeof(__int8) == sizeof(char) == 1
sizeof(__int16) == sizeof(short) == 2
sizeof(__int32) == sizeof(int) == 4
sizeof(__int64) == sizeof(long long) == 8
```

Comment: can clarify your question little bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sizes of the primitive types `int`, `char`, `short`, `long`, etc. are implementation-defined and can vary from system to system.  All that you're guaranteed is that

- `sizeof(char) == 1`, and
- `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`.

As a result, many platforms provide their own custom, non-portable types that are guaranteed to be the given sizes.  For example, I am fairly confident that Microsoft guarantees that `__int8` is always eight bits, `__int16` is always 16 bits, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are guaranteed a little more than that -- char is at least 8 bits, short at least 16, long at least 32 and long long (if present) at least 64.